# How to put the contents of a json file into an array using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have an external file **contacts.json**. How I can convert it to a javascript array?
this is the **contacts.json** content:

```
{
    "ppl1":{
        "Name":"Jhon",
        "Surname":"Kenneth",
        "mobile":329129293,
        "email":"jhon@gmail.com"
    },
    "ppl2":{
        "Name":"Thor",
        "Surname":"zvalk",
        "mobile":349229293,
        "email":"thor@gmail.com"
    },
    "ppl3":{
        "Name":"Mila",
        "Surname":"Kvuls",
        "mobile":329121293,
        "email":"mila@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this external file on your own server?

Comment: Here is some useful information about it: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/.

Comment: yeah, this file is in my server

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solved:

```
$.getJSON('contacts.json', function (json) {
var array = [];
for (var key in json) {
    if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var item = json[key];
        array.push({
            name: item.Name,
            surname: item.Surname,
            mobile: item.mobile,
            email: item.email
        });            
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var items = [];
$.each(JSONObject.results.bindings, function(i, obj) {
    items.push([obj.place.value, obj.lat.value, obj.long.value, obj.page.value]);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Answered [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356370/convert-array-of-json-object-strings-to-array-of-js-objects).

```
// JavaScript array of JavaScript objects
var objs = json_string.map(JSON.parse);

// ...or for older browsers
var objs=[];
for (var i=json_string.map.length;i--;) objs[i]=JSON.parse(json_string.map[i]);

// ...or for maximum speed:
var objs = JSON.parse('['+json_string.map.join(',')+']');
```

Comment: Strings don't have a `.map` method.