# How to convert form arrays to JSON in Javascript? (array of objects)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, forms

HTML:

```
<form id="products">
<tbody id="product-list">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="type[]" value="jackets">jackets</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="name[]" value="test1">test1</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="color[]" value="red">red</td><td>
    <input type="hidden" name="size[]" value="S">S</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="type[]" value="jackets">jackets</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="name[]" value="test2">test2</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="color[]" value="blue">blue</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="size[]" value="S">S</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</form>
```

JS:

```
JSON.stringify($("#products").serializeArray();
```

Output:

```
[{"name":"type[]","value":"jackets"},{"name":"name[]","value":"test1"},{"name":"color[]","value":"red"},{"name":"size[]","value":"S"},{"name":"type[]","value":"jackets"},{"name":"name[]","value":"test2"},{"name":"color[]","value":"blue"},{"name":"size[]","value":"S"}]
```

Desired Output:

An array of objects, so something like this (just a visual)

```
Object[0].type -> "jackets"
Object[0].name -> "test1"
Object[0].color -> "red"
Object[0].size -> "S"
Object[1].type -> "jackets"
Object[1].name -> "test2"
Object[1].color -> "blue"
Object[1].size -> "S"
```

Ideally, I'm looking for the solution how to do this, as well as the logic in order to learn.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356370/convert-array-of-json-object-strings-to-array-of-js-objects check this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the `tbody` element is a child of a `table` element.

Then, here is what you could do:

```js
var arr = $("#product-list tr").get().map(function (tr) {
    return $('input', tr).get().reduce(function (obj, input) {
        obj[input.name.replace(/\[.*\]/,'')] = input.value;
        return obj;
    }, {});
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="products">
<table>
<tbody id="product-list">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="type[]" value="jackets">jackets</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="name[]" value="test1">test1</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="color[]" value="red">red</td><td>
    <input type="hidden" name="size[]" value="S">S</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="type[]" value="jackets">jackets</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="name[]" value="test2">test2</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="color[]" value="blue">blue</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="size[]" value="S">S</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

The `get()` method will convert a jQuery collection to a plain array, and for the first occurrence, that will be an array of 2 elements, since there are two `tr` elements.

The second one will return an array with 4 elements, both times, since both `tr` elements have 4 `input` elements. But this array of 4 elements is converted to an object with 4 properties via `reduce`, which iterates over those `inputs` and adds a property for each of them to the object that starts out as an empty one (`{}`).

The call `replace(/\[.*\]/,'')` will remove the bracketed part from the name attribute values.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array.prototype.map()` to add a key in each object that corresponds to the value you are looking for:

```
var arr = [{"name":"type[]","value":"jackets"},{"name":"name[]","value":"test1"},{"name":"color[]","value":"red"},{"name":"size[]","value":"S"},{"name":"type[]","value":"jackets"},{"name":"name[]","value":"test2"},{"name":"color[]","value":"blue"},{"name":"size[]","value":"S"}];

var result = arr.map(function(elem){
  elem[elem.name.replace(/\W/g, '')] = elem.value; //adds key "type" with value "jackets"
  return elem;
});

result[0].jackets //"jackets"
```

Comment: Hey where does `a` come from? It's undefined? Also this is the output: `[{"name":"type[]","value":"jackets","jackets":"jackets"},{"name":"name[]","value":"test1","test1":"test1"},{"name":"color[]","value":"red","red":"red"},{"name":"size[]","value":"S","S":"S"},{"name":"type[]","value":"jackets","jackets":"jackets"},{"name":"name[]","value":"test2","test2":"test2"},{"name":"color[]","value":"blue","blue":"blue"},{"name":"size[]","value":"S","S":"S"}]`

Comment: ah sorry! was typo

Comment: @sieuPhan a is arr

Comment: This produces an array with 8 elements instead of 2, and each of the 8 objects has either 2 or 3 properties. For instance there is `{ name: test1, value: test1 }` included.

Comment: oh - i hadn't realized that it shouldve only been 2 elements. will update.