# Get Multiple keys from redis server and parse json without loop using node JS

Tags: php, node.js, redis, lumen

I am switching my REST API from lumen to node, data was stored on redis in key value format but as lumen cache lib support serialize data so all the data was in serialize format in redis but In node.js to achieve that was need  to use php-serializer package or use loop to decode data getting from redis.

To avoid this condition I have stored data on redis in JSON format but try to get from redis using mget but I am getting data in string format.

```
client.mget(["data1", "data2", "data3"], function (err, res) {
    console.dir(res);
});
```

I know from JSON.parse I can get json value but I don't want to run loop to convert each value to JSON array.

Please suggest how can we achieve JSON data from redis.Do I need to use any framework on nodejs or need to change stored data on redis.

Currently I am storing data in this format in redis.

SS : http://prntscr.com/krkvbp

If I am fetching only one key by using this code :

```
client.get("data1", function(err, reply) {
    // reply is null when the key is missing
    var cacheData = JSON.parse(reply);
    console.log(cacheData.mId);
});
```

So I can get proper JSON object from JSON.parse but If I want to get data in bunch using .

```
client.mget(["data1", "data1", "data1"], function (err, res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Than I got response like that.

SS: http://prntscr.com/krkxl4

I don't want to run loop for each index on array.Please suggest Is there any package to achieve it or need to add any framework  or change in store procedure.

Previously I was stored in this way (Unserialize format).

SS : http://prntscr.com/krkz0u

Comment: You can use `JSON.parse()` function. Ex: `JSON.parse(res)`

Comment: I already mentioned JSON.parse will parse one index not all index array

Comment: I think you can find a solution here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356370/convert-array-of-json-object-strings-to-array-of-js-objects

Comment: @giankotarola,I have checked but it is not fully converted to JSON gettin one node like this  pImgURL: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],